# Wanting to know the best way to add Subtitles in Tableview for a list of txt files?

Tags: swift

I have a list of rearrangeable txt files and I have their Titles listed in a table view, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to add subtitles. I would like to have the Titles be the name of texts in their foreign language and the subtitle be the translated name.

Currently, I have listed titles like this:

```
stories = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "txt", subdirectory: nil)!
```

And then I add file name and strip extension like so:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = stories[indexPath.row].deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
```

One way I thought of doing it was putting all of the lines of txt files into a string array and then putting subtitle in the txt files at line 1 and then pulling that in as a subtitle in tableview. But I'm not sure how to do this yet without reading entire files of the txt and then reading line 1. Is there a way to read just the first line of all the text tiles and put them in a subtitle array that corresponds with the titles?

Second way I thought was to maybe add the original language and the translation titles into the file names for the txt files, separated by a "-" or symbol. Is there a way to read the text before a hyphen as one string and the text after as a second string?

Is there another better way to go about this?

Added: The stories open with this method.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController {
            vc.selectedStory = stories[indexPath.row]
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Update: On a whim I decided to create a dictionary like so:

```
var storyTitles:[String:String] = [
   "foreign lang title A":"english translation A",
   "foreign lang title B":"english translation B",
]
```

and added all of my foreign language titles: translated titles.

Then I plugged it into cell.detailText like so and it worked!

```
 let storyForeignTitle = stories[indexPath.row].deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
        cell.textLabel?.text = storyForeignTitle
        let storyEnglishTitle = storyTitles[storyForeignTitle]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = storyEnglishTitle
```

So now final question: I'll have about 50 stories total. Are there any downsides to the solution I came up with? I was worried that it wouldn't work because the foreign language is not a latin text but it seems to be okay in my simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Using your method of using **One Text File for each story**, you could store the title and translation separated by a comma:

`Title1,Translation1`

Create a Story Struct:

```
struct Story {
    var title: String
    var translation: String
}
```

Initialise an empty `Array` of `Story` objects

```
var stories = [Story]()
```

Read your text files:

```
if let textfileURLs = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "txt", subdirectory: nil) {

    for url in textfileURLs {

        do {
            let textFile = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)
            let data = textFile.components(separatedBy: ",")
            if data.count == 2 {
                let title = data[0], translation = data[1]
                stories.append(Story(title: title, translation: translation))
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error reading text file")
        }
    }
}
```

In `numberOfRowsInSection`:

```
return stories.count
```

Then in `cellForRowAt indexPath` you can get the title and subtitle from each story object:

```
    cell.textLabel?.text = stories[indexPath.row].title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = stories[indexPath.row].translation
```

**Alternative Method using a Single Text File**

Depending on your use case it would probably be more efficient to just store all the stories in one text file like this:

```
Title1,Translation1
Title2,Translation2
Title3,Translation3
```

You can then parse the data like this:

```
    if let textFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "StoryTitles", withExtension: "txt") {

        do {
            let textFile = try String(contentsOf: textFileURL, encoding: .utf8)
            let data = textFile.components(separatedBy: "\n")

            for row in data {
                let storyData = row.components(separatedBy: ",")
                if storyData.count == 2 {
                    let title = storyData[0], translation = storyData[1]
                    stories.append(Story(title: title, translation: translation))
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error reading text file")
        }
    }
```

Comment: The first method works for me, but I'd like to use the second method. I added an rtf file with all the titles, translations, then the struct, empty array, and parsed. The issue is that this way breaks my code that lets the user click on a row to read the story. How do I fix that? I added the code to my post above.

Comment: Added an update now. I tried a dictionary and it seems to be working. Any downside to this method? I add the code to original post. I was worried that it wouldn't work because the foreign language is not a latin text but it seems to be okay.